# Filter products based on a custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, query-string, custom-fields

I have a question regarding custom fields in WooCommerce: Is there any way to display products based on custom field meta key and value?

I created a product custom field for delivery, the meta key is `custom_text_field_delivery`, and values are, `24h`, `5days` and `7days`.

Then I tried to get them by URL like: `localhost/shop/?custom_text_field_delivery=24h`, but it didn't worked.

Is there any way to display them or I should create single page for each option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following, to filter products based on a custom field in a query string with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_products_with_custom_field', 10, 2 );
function filter_products_with_custom_field( $meta_query, $query ) {
    $meta_key = 'custom_text_field_delivery'; // <= Here define the meta key
    
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET[$meta_key]) && ! empty($_GET[$meta_key]) ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
           'key'   => $meta_key,
           'value' => esc_attr($_GET[$meta_key]),
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

You will be able to filter products by URL like: `localhost/shop/?custom_text_field_delivery=24h`.

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: It works, thanks LoicTheAztex, You save me 3 times this month. *__*

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can this be modified to work with an array of custom fields? And also to have it work with AND query to have multiple values selected at once?

Comment: What if we want up to 5 days? I mean it will list let's say between 2 and 5 days. Something like `custom_text_field_delivery=2-5` My custom field contains only numbers.

Comment: I added `'compare' => 'BETWEEN',` and now it works with plus sign. ?days=2+5 filters between 2 and 5. But if I enter only one number like 2, it causes a PHP notice: **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php on line 743** 

How to prevent this error?